# Json written textfile - finding all integers

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a .txt file written as it is a json file. 
There is a lot of list, dicts, integers etc. inside and I need to get out all numbers from there and return it's sum.

> {"e":[[{"e":86,"c":23,"a":{"a":[120,169,"green","red","orange"],"b":"red"},"g":"yellow","b":["yellow"],"d":"red","f":-19},{"e":-47,"a":[2iolet"},"c":"green","h":"orange","b":{"e":59,"a":"yellow","d":"green","c":47,"h":"red","b":"blue","g":"orange","f":["violet",43,168,78]},"g":"orange","f":[{"e":[82,-41,2,"red","violet","orange","yellow"],"c":"green","a":77,"g":"orange","b":147,"d":49,"f":"blue"},-1,142,136,[":41,"f":63},11,-20,{"e":[100,43,183],"a":"yellow","d":["orange","yellow","violet","yellow",143,162,-23,168,145,-33]}

this is just a little part of this file.

```
def list_dig(lst):
    tmp_int = 0
    for element in lst:
        if type(element) == dict:
            dict_dig(element)
        elif type(element) == int:
            tmp_int += element
        elif type(element) == list:
            list_dig(element)
    return tmp_int


def dict_dig(dictionary):
    tmp_int = 0
    for key in dictionary:
        if type(dictionary[key]) == list:
            tmp_int += list_dig(dictionary[key])
        elif type(dictionary[key]) == int:
            tmp_int += dictionary[key]
        elif type(dictionary[key]) == dict:
            dict_dig(dictionary[key])
    return tmp_int


with open('json_written.txt', 'r') as file:
    counter = 0
    tmp = file.read()
    for i in tmp:
        if type(i) == list:
            counter += list_dig(i)
        elif type(i) == dict:
            counter += dict_dig(i)
        elif type(i) == int:
            counter += i

    print(counter)
```

I wrote something like that, but I'm sure that's trash, because it keeps returning 0 as a counter and I'm stucked. How could I solve this problem? Maybe should I use pandas, but if yes- how? 
Thanks for all answers

Comment: can you explain what it is you are trying to sum and what the conditions to sum are? that would help in getting an answer, thanks! also are you controlling how the data gets written to this file? it is very messy/unorganized and has some syntax errors in it, for example `a":[2iolet"}` is not valid

Comment: You json is invalid.

Comment: That's weird, because I got this file with exact task: (...)
The accounting software uses a peculiar storage format. They have a JSON document which contains a
variety of things: lists ([1,2,3]), dictionaries ({"a":1, "b":2}), numbers, and strings. Your job is to simply
find all of the numbers throughout the document and add them together.

Link to full file: https://pastebin.com/azc6e9fD

Comment: [mcve], [mcve], [mcve]

Comment: Have you read anything on parsing JSON in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved a problem.

So json file isn't written correctly so I had to find other solution to count a sum of all integers inside this file.

I decided to make a list characters to replace, treat all file as a string and replace all unwanted characters for x, then split it by x and remove empty fields. Then I converted all fields from strings to integers and finally just added them all together.

Do you see anything what I could simplify?

```
char_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
             '{','}','"',':','[',']','(',')',',']


with open("skychallenge_accounting_input.txt", 'r') as file:
    sky_data = file.read()

    for char in char_list:
        sky_data = sky_data.replace(char, 'x')

    sky_list = sky_data.split('x')

    while '' in sky_list:
        sky_list.remove('')

    for i in range(len(sky_list)):
        sky_list[i] = int(sky_list[i])

    print(sum(sky_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `json` module to load in the nested dict, otherwise the text file won't be recognnized as a dict or list, just a string:

```
import json

with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Now you can use a recursive function with `isinstance` to sum all the integers:

```
def recursive_sum_ints(some_dict, total=0):
    for v in some_dict.values():
        if isinstance(v, int):
             total += v
        elif isinstance(v, list):
             total += sum(x for x in v if isinstance(x, int))
        else:
             total += recursive_sum_ints(v, total)
    return total
```

Then simply call

```
result = recursive_sum_ints(data)
print(result)
```

Comment: Well, if I do it like that I'm getting error : 


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read',  that's about that json.load()

Comment: @MrLok3rs You need to open the file first before reading. with open("text.txt") as stream: data = json.load(stream)

Comment: added to answer, minor difference in how api works in my memory.